# VLC udp stream stops after any interrupt or track change in lan in mac os

Tags: macos, streaming, vlc, audio-streaming, macos-sierra

I am trying to stream audio in lan network in mac os sierra with vlc version 2.2.5.1 Umbrella.

I am able to stream my playlist .xspf file. But it stops after one song finish or track change and need to reconnect again in client machine (receiver). I am using default vlc wizard to stream setup.

I tried sout keep , sout all and gather. Also i tried to encode all songs in same format by selecting trancode audio.But nothing worked for me.Perhaps i am trying commands in wrong order.It works fine for windows 7 os.Please guide me in this what's going wrong?

Below are MRL generating by vlc wizard.

[image]

here is what i am receving log in receiver machine,

```
 /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/share/lua/meta/art
core debug: no art finder modules matched
core debug: art not found for aa
macosx debug: releasing old sleep blocker (34696)
macosx debug: prevented sleep through IOKit (34702)
ts debug: PMTCallBack called
ts debug: new PMT program number=1 version=2 pid_pcr=68
ts debug:   * es pid=68 type=3 dr->i_tag=0xa
ts debug: found language: 
ts debug:   * es pid=68 type=3 fcc=mpga
ts warning: discontinuity received 0x0 instead of 0x9 (pid=68)
core warning: clock gap, unexpected stream discontinuity
core warning: feeding synchro with a new reference point trying to recover from clock gap
core debug: discarded audio buffer
mpeg_audio debug: emulated startcode (no startcode on following frame)
core debug: discarded audio buffer
core debug: discarded audio buffer
core debug: discarded audio buffer
core debug: discarded audio buffer
core debug: discarded audio buffer
core debug: discarded audio buffer
core debug: discarded audio buffer
core debug: discarded audio buffer
core debug: discarded audio buffer
core warning: clock gap, unexpected stream discontinuity
core warning: feeding synchro with a new reference point trying to recover from clock gap
clock error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 0, bound 3000000)
core error: Could not convert timestamp 55337150977
core debug: discarded audio buffer
clock error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 0, bound 3000000)
core error: Could not convert timestamp 55337177099
core debug: discarded audio buffer
clock error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 0, bound 3000000)
core error: Could not convert timestamp 55337203222
core debug: discarded audio buffer
clock error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 0, bound 3000000)
core error: Could not convert timestamp 55337229344
core debug: discarded audio buffer
clock error: Timestamp conversion failed (delay 1000000, buffering 0, bound 3000000)
core error: Could not convert timestamp 55337255466
core debug: discarded audio buffer
```

Comment: Can you share the 0 (errors) and 2(debug) messages from "Tools --> Messages".

Comment: i am not getting any error,warning or message. Console is clear.I am able to play first song then it stops.

Comment: It s impossible. Please open "Tool ---> Messages" in VLC Media Player and then select 2(debug) hit enter. Then start your UDP stream and share messages(Debug)

Comment: @SalihKaragöz i updated my question with messages.